# How do I add watchdog to my python executable

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I am using Python 3.4 on Windows and have tried both py2exe and cx_freeze.  When I try to use the instructions on:

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs

I get an error message saying that **path** is undefined.  In the hack section below I don't know how to perform step 3.  Do I just manually copy past all of the individual .py files into the source directory?  Wasn't sure what data_files represented.

Both scripts say that I have a number of missing modules related to the watchdog package.

Comment: I assume you have to place place all of the package files into your project directory

Comment: I added the files to the data_files portion of the setup.py but still have issues.  I still have about 7 of the watchdog modules missing and now the after the build is done, its not able to import watchdog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to be a problem with python 3.4.  When I switched to python 2.7.10 everything worked as it should.